# Converting Twitter's date format to Datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime, twitter, utc

Twitter's API kicks out a date in this format:

```
Thu, 18 Oct 2012 09:37:01 +0000
```

Is it possible to convert this into a datetime format using PHP, for my database? E.g.

```
2012-10-18 09:37:01
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("Thu, 18 Oct 2012 09:37:01 +0000") );
```

Comment: That's OK, but returned value will be localized time with current timezone offset added (e.g. 11:37:01 for me). Just strip off +0000 before and you will get correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Datetime Object from format

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, j M Y H:i:s +0000', 'Thu, 18 Oct 2012 09:37:01 +0000');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```